# SAS proc XSL error

Tags: xml, xslt, sas

I have a XML file that I would like to transform using a populated xsl sheet.  SAS has a Proc XSL that should be able to perfrom this task, but instead I get the following error

> ERROR: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 6
>          errors detected.
>   ERROR: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed

Has anyone else encountered an error like this?  Is it a java error related to SAS or is the problem with my XSL file (see the full file below).``

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:d7p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d5p1="http://www.itron.com/ami/2008/10/events" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.itron.com/ami/2008/10/common" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.itron.com/ami/2008/10/data" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:itron="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Itron.Ami.AmiServiceTest.Hosting" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" xmlns:local="#local-functions" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">


-<xsl:template match="/">

<div>AMI DATA</div>


-<xsl:for-each select="XMLRoot/itron:DataSubscriberItem">


-<div>

<xsl:variable select="itron:DataArrivedInput/d2p1:ReadDataCollection/d2p1:ReadData/d2p1:LoadProfileChannels/d2p1:LoadProfileChannel/d2p1:TimeDataEnd" name="EndTime"/>
Time Data End: 
<xsl:value-of select="$EndTime"/>

</div>


-<div>

<xsl:variable select="itron:DataArrivedInput/d2p1:ReadDataCollection/d2p1:ReadData/d2p1:LoadProfileChannels/d2p1:LoadProfileChannel/d2p1:PulseMultiplier" name="PulsMult"/>
Pulse Multiplier: 
<xsl:value-of select="$PulsMult"/>

</div>


-<div>
Meter ID: 
<xsl:value-of select="itron:DataArrivedInput/d2p1:ReadDataCollection/d2p1:ReadData/d2p1:Identifier"/>

</div>


-<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">


-<tr style="background-color:#C0C0C0; font-weight:bold">

<td>Num</td>

<td>Vh(a)</td>

<td>Max V(a)</td>

<td>Min V(a)</td>

<td>Vh(c)</td>

<td>Max V(c)</td>

<td>Min V(c)</td>

<td>Timestamp</td>

</tr>

<xsl:variable select="count(itron:DataArrivedInput/d2p1:ReadDataCollection/d2p1:ReadData/d2p1:LoadProfileChannels/d2p1:LoadProfileChannel[1]/d2p1:IntervalValues/d2p1:IntervalValue)" name="NumPnts"/>


-<div>
Number of Points: 
<xsl:value-of select="$NumPnts"/>

</div>


-<xsl:for-each select="itron:DataArrivedInput/d2p1:ReadDataCollection/d2p1:ReadData/d2p1:LoadProfileChannels/d2p1:LoadProfileChannel[1]/d2p1:IntervalValues/d2p1:IntervalValue">

<xsl:variable select="position()" name="INum"/>

<xsl:variable select="../../d2p1:TimeDataEnd" name="EndTime2"/>


-<tr>


-<td>

<xsl:value-of select="$INum"/>

</td>

<xsl:variable select="d2p1:ChannelValue" name="Vha"/>


-<td>

<!--<xsl:value-of select="$Vha*$PulsMult"/>-->


<xsl:value-of select="format-number($Vha*$PulsMult,"0.###")"/>

</td>

<xsl:variable select="../../../d2p1:LoadProfileChannel[2]/d2p1:IntervalValues/d2p1:IntervalValue[$INum]/d2p1:ChannelValue" name="Vmaxa"/>


-<td>

<xsl:value-of select="format-number($Vmaxa*$PulsMult,"0.###")"/>

</td>

<xsl:variable select="../../../d2p1:LoadProfileChannel[3]/d2p1:IntervalValues/d2p1:IntervalValue[$INum]/d2p1:ChannelValue" name="Vmina"/>


-<td>

<xsl:value-of select="format-number($Vmina*$PulsMult,"0.###")"/>

</td>

<xsl:variable select="../../../d2p1:LoadProfileChannel[4]/d2p1:IntervalValues/d2p1:IntervalValue[$INum]/d2p1:ChannelValue" name="Vhc"/>


-<td>

<xsl:value-of select="format-number($Vhc*$PulsMult,"0.###")"/>

</td>

<xsl:variable select="../../../d2p1:LoadProfileChannel[5]/d2p1:IntervalValues/d2p1:IntervalValue[$INum]/d2p1:ChannelValue" name="Vmaxc"/>


-<td>

<xsl:value-of select="format-number($Vmaxc*$PulsMult,"0.###")"/>

</td>

<xsl:variable select="../../../d2p1:LoadProfileChannel[6]/d2p1:IntervalValues/d2p1:IntervalValue[$INum]/d2p1:ChannelValue" name="Vminc"/>


-<td>

<xsl:value-of select="format-number($Vminc*$PulsMult,"0.###")"/>

</td>


-<td>

<xsl:variable select="concat(substring($EndTime2, 1,10), ' ', substring($EndTime2, 12,5))" name="SDTS"/>

<xsl:value-of select="local:timeCalc($SDTS, $INum, $NumPnts)"/>

</td>

</tr>

</xsl:for-each>

</table>

<hr/>

</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>


-<msxsl:script language="VBScript" implements-prefix="local">

<![CDATA[ Function timeCalc(ET, PT, TP) SDT1 = CDate(ET) SDT = DateAdd("n", -(TP-PT)*5, SDT1) TTR = PadOut(Month(SDT)) & "/" & PadOut(Day(SDT)) & "/" & Year(SDT)& " " & PadOut(Hour(SDT)-4) & ":" & PadOut(Minute(SDT)) timeCalc = TTR End Function Function PadOut(n) If n < 10 Then PadOut = "0" & n Else PadOut = n End If End Function ]]>

</msxsl:script>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my SAS code

```
PROC XSL in='C:\SAS Files\input.XML'
    OUT='C:\SAS Files\output.XML'
    XSL='C:\SAS Files\stylesheet.xsl';
    run;
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717652/how-to-resolve-javax-xml-transform-transformerconfigurationexception) for example.  This means you likely have an error in your stylesheet (apparently, 6 of them).  It's possible you simply have errors, or that SAS doesn't fully support everything you have in there - I don't know well enough to say.  Perhaps an XML expert can give more useful feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Use different quotes within an expression.

Use

```
select="format-number($Vha*$PulsMult,'0.###')"
```

instead of

```
select="format-number($Vha*$PulsMult,"0.###")"
```

Comment: Sorry, the data didn't copy over from the xsl file correctly.  I do have the correct quotes in the source file, it just didn't paste correctly into my question.